# Read files from folders inside a folder

Tags: node.js

So basically I have a folder, which holds other folders and each folder has it's own set of images, that I would like to display in a `'ul'`. The problem is since I'm using `readdir`, which is `async`, how can I write the `response`, without getting a **"Write after `.end()` error"**. Here is how my code looks like.

```
    var fs = require('fs'),
    url = require('url');

module.exports = function(req, res) {
    req.pathName = req.pathName || url.parse(req.url).pathname;

    if(req.pathName === '/gallery') {
        fs.readdir('./content/images/public', function(err, filenames) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }

            if(filenames.length) {
                var list_content = '';

                for (var i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
                    fs.readdir('./content/images/public/' + filenames[i], function(err, images) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            return;
                        }

                        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                            list_content += '<li><a href="/gallery/details/'+ i +'">' + images[i] + '</a></li>';
                        }

                        var list = '<ul>' + list_content + '</ul><a href="/">Go back to homepage</a>';

                        res.writeHead(200, {
                            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                        });
                        res.send(list);
                    });
                }
            } else {
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                });
                res.write('<p>There are no images in the gallery</p><a href="/">Go back to homepage</a>');
                res.end();
            }
        });
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
                    res.end();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using res.write() and res.end(), try using res.send(), which does both for you. UPDATE: Also, make sure this code is within a request callback where req, and res object is parsed correctly.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   list_content += '<li><a href="/gallery/details/'+ i +'">' + images[i] + '</a></li>';
    }

   var list = '<ul>' + list_content + '</ul><a href="/">Go back to homepage</a>';

 res.send(list);
```

then on the front end, receive it in the ajax response callback, like

```
$.post('xxxx', function(response){
      alert(response); //list
});
```

UPDATE: after seeing your updated code,

```
module.exports = function(req, res) {
```

doesnt make sense, it needs to be something like

```
exports.functionName = function(req,res){
```

read this

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

module.exports is an **object** of **functions**. Not a function. It looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  funcExample: function() {
    return 2;
  },

  funcOtherExample: function() {
    return 1;
  }
```

Comment: I get an error that says "res.send()" is not a function

Comment: Ok. that must be because you are not calling this async function within a route ? Where if your function(req,res)? please show more of your surrounding code and ill have a look.

Comment: I've edited my question, by placing all the code in my .js file

Comment: I export all my modules and then call them in a function like this 

`var http = require('http'),
 fs = require('fs'),
 url = require('url'),
 handlers = require('./handlers/main');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  for(var handler of handlers) {
   var proceed = handler(req, res);

   if(!proceed) {
    break;
   }
  }
 })
 .listen(7357);`

Comment: You arent making much sense. ill update my answer more.

Comment: that's not the problem dude :)

Comment: It is because it means req,res are not being parsed correctly. Try console.log the res object.

Comment: I did that and it has no problems with it

Comment: Okay - ive also just noticed you have res.end() at the very end. try remove it. As it may be calling before the file system call back.